# Does absolute integrability imply the existence of integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I thought absolute integrability, i.e,
$$\int_a^b|f(t)|dt<\infty$$
imply the existence of $$\int_a^bf(t)dt.$$

However, I found that some mathematicians like G.N. Watson and G. Polya mentioned the two conditions seperately in their books and papers.

If I am mistaken, can anyone give a counter-example?

Comment: The other implication is not true.

Comment: In measure theory existence and finiteness of the second integral is equivalent to the finiteness of the  first integral for measurable functions.

Comment: The big question is whether your intergrals are Riemann integrals or Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: And if they are Riemann integrals, are they proper or improper?

Comment: I think Watson and Polya only considered Riemann integrals, possibly improper in the sense that f may have integrable poles while a, b are finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication is false, as far as Riemann integration is concerned. I shall provide a counterexample.

Take $a = 0$, $b = 1$, i.e. consider the interval $[0,1]$. Define $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ as $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x\in \mathbb Q\\ -1 & x\notin \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$
Clearly, $|f|$ is Riemann integrable (it is the constant function equal to $1$), but $f$ is not.

Comment: $f$ is integrable in Lebesgue sense.

Comment: I agree. It is unclear whether the OP is talking about Riemann integration or Lebesgue.

Comment: Thank you for your counter-example. Can this phenomenon happen even if f is continuous?

Comment: Impossible. Continuous functions are Riemann integrable. If $f$ is continuous, so is $|f|$. In this case, both $f$ and $|f|$ are Riemann integrable. @MikePark


Find a proof here: https://webspace.clarkson.edu/~pathaval/continuous.pdf

Comment: What if f is continuous only on (a,b) so that f may have integrable poles or unbounded variation?

Comment: @MikePark As long as $f$ is bounded, we don't have a problem. Note the following well-known result in Riemann integration: If $f$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$, and there is a finite set $E \subset [a,b]$ such that $f$ is continuous at every point of $[a,b]\setminus E$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. In your case, if $f$ is continuous only on $[a,b]$, we can take $E = \{a,b\}$; and $f$ is still Riemann-integrable by the stated result.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor Thanks a lot.